# why can i import this type from a xsd schema?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, xsd

In the schema below, the line `<xs:element type="cmn:AddressType" name="ResidentialAddress" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />` gives an error `Type 'http://company.com/Common:AddressType' is not declared`.

Does anyone know why? It shows in the Visual Studio 2008 editor, and also if I try validate an XML file with `XDocument`.

Schema Student.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Student"
    xmlns:cmn="http://company.com/Common"
    targetNamespace="http://company.com/Student"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

  <xs:import id="cmn" schemaLocation="Address.xsd" 
             namespace="http://company.com/Common" />

  <xs:element name="Student" nillable="false">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:integer" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"  />
        <xs:element type="cmn:AddressType" name="ResidentialAddress" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Schema Address.xsd:

```
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://company.com/Common"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="AddressType">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Line1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Line2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The question should be "why can't i" not "why can i".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you actually declared AddressType as an *element*, not a *type*. If you want to use it as an element in your main schema, use:

```
<xs:element ref="cmn:AddressType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
```

If you want it to be a type, then  get rid of the element declaration in your address schema and put in `<xs:complexType name="AddressType">` instead.